# Multiple Aux route on same component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Can we add multiple aux route in the same component view in Angular 2 and if they both can be activated at the same time? If yes what can be the URL for the same?

Angular 2 version : `2.0.0-rc.4`

Angular Router version: `3.0.0-beta.2`

**app.html**

```
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <router-outlet name='aux1'></router-outlet>
  <router-outlet name='aux2'></router-outlet>
```

**route configuration**

```
   { path: "route1", component: route1Component }
   { path: "aux1-route", component: aux1RouteComponent, outlet: "aux1" }
   { path: "aux2-route", component: aux2RouteComponent, outlet: "aux2" }
```

With one aux route the URL can be,

```
  #/route1(aux1:aux1-route)
  #/route1(aux2:aux2-route)
```

above routes work,
what about with multiple route, I tried with below but it does not work

```
  #/route1(aux1:aux1-route)(aux2:aux2-route)
```

Any idea why it is not working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with router 3.0.0-beta.2? Aux routes had several issues with fixes already in master which will be included with the next release.

Comment: No luck with , "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2" too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this, the URL needs to be corrected like below,

```
   /route1(aux1:aux1-route//aux2:aux2-route)
```

Here is the [Plunker!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/5DElSz6QslBljFtoHzrc?p=preview)